# How long does Safenet track IPs for?

Tags: hacker-experience

Does Safenet track your IP indefinitely (or until someone finds you or it escalates to an FBI wanted warrant)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safenet puts you off the list after **1 hour** for `illegal transfer` or `delete file` reasons. I did not test the DDoS reason to see if it is 1 hour too.

One way to circumvent these warnings is to change your IP address at your ISP, although it's not recommended to waste an IP change only for that.

Comment: One time I was on Safenet for over 24 hours for DDoSing someone. During the time I was on Safenet, I didn't do any other illegal stuff (hacking bank accounts, DDoSing others, ect). I feel that the time that you are on Safenet is dependent on how big or strong the action that you did to get on Safenet.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, they do not, but they don't alert you when you fall off the list.  You may want to occasionally check Safenet's list of tracked IPs (I suggest using your browser's find function and just searching for the first two numbers of your IP) to see if you're still on the watchlist.

Comment: I'm still doing tests, trying to get picked by safenet again to see how long that lasts. Found out I was off the list after a few hours offline today.